# three.js -- Line does not pass through vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a very basic question --

I plotted some vertices (representing stars) as part of `THREE.Geometry`

```
var constellationGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
for (var i = 0; i < starCount; i ++) {
        var x = xScale(unfiltered[i].x);
        var y = yScale(unfiltered[i].y);
        var z = zScale(unfiltered[i].z);

        var star = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
        constellationGeo.vertices.push(star);
}
```

Then I drew a line with a view of joining them into a constellation:

```
var line = new THREE.Line(constellationGeo, lineMaterial);
scene.add(line);
```

However, my line does not pass through the points. Seems I am missing something basic here?

Comment: What do you mean? Is there an offset?

Comment: Maybe you can setup a jsfiddle or provide an image to illuminate your problem.

Comment: So i re-created my scene using the boilerplate given on the three.js wiki and it worked just fine. My earlier code was a bit more complex with several objects nested, so the question is now closed though i do not know exactly what i did wrong in the first attempt. The above snippet looks correct too. I want to close this question but thanks for your comments !